# How to set correct measurements

Tags: scale, measurement

I have a floor plan and as per image i have scale the reference image. Started with the elevator 5x5.6 that looks perfect in size marked in red. But with the terrace 6.6x19 feet why it's not matching the red rectangle.

[image]

Anyway to fix.

[image]

Comment: I suspect that plan is not drawn to scale. For instance the 10' x 12' bedroom is wrong too as is the 10' dimension at the bottom of the plan.

Comment: i agree with John. The plan is wrong.

Comment: @JohnEason can i share the pdf file?

Comment: No point really. I've extracted the image from the blend file but don't really have an accurate way of measuring it here.